# Katalon Studio - SwitchToWebView does not work in iOS real device

Tags: ios, iphone, webview, katalon-studio

I am writing an automation script for iOS App.

I was writing the script that supports iOS simulator. But , I was unable to receive notifications (and it is not possible as per Apple and various other forums). So, I switched to automation of App for iOS real device. Now, my already created script for iOS simulator is not working as expected in iOS real device.

As my App is a hybrid Cordova App, I had to switch to and fro between mobile and web view many a times.

But I am receiving the following error trying to switch my App's content to webView :

com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Unable to switch the driver to WEBVIEW mode (Root cause: Cannot find any WEBVIEW to switch to)

The specifications are as under :

Mac OS : 10.13.6
Appium version : 1.8.1
Xcode version : 9.4.1
Katalon Studio Version: 5.8.0
Device used in Testing : iPhone 6 (OS:11.4.1)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what `driver.getContextHandles()` returning in real device ? Also try to give some wait before getting available contexts and see if it works ?

Comment: unable to find any such method. Instead, it is displaying the method .getWindowHandles. Do I need to import something to get it working ?